# Roman numbering in table of contents using report

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering

Using the MWE below, I want the chapters declaration, preface and abstract to be given a `roman` number in the table of contents and the rest of the chapters `arabic` numbers, using the report class. The table of contents, however, seems to ignore the chapters I want to be `roman` numbered. It is possible if I use `memoir` rather than report, but than the `subsection`s are not shown in the table of contents.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter*{Declaration}
\chapter*{Preface}
\chapter*{Abstract}
\chapter{Introduction}
\chapter{Topics in Claims Reserving}
\section{section 1}
\subsection{section2}
\chapter{Conclusion}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You are aware that `\chapter*` is the version of `\chapter` which does not have numbers and no entry to the ToC? No number, no Roman number output ;-)

Comment: You seem to want Roman *page* numbers up to the abstract; is this so? Or do you mean Roman numbers for the chapters like “Chapter I Declaration” and “Chapter II Preface”?

Comment: @egreg: No, I think the OP wants Roman chapter numbering: Chapter I, Chapter II ...

Comment: Note that in order to have subsections in the TOC with `memoir`, you just have to issue `\settocdepth{subsection}` in the preamble.

Comment: The missing entries for `subsection` can be obtained by saying `\setcounter{tocnumdepth}{2}` and `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `book` and then it has `\frontmatter` for the very same purpose. (Same is possible with `memoir`, you can always change the `tocdepth`)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Declaration}
\chapter{Preface}
\chapter{Abstract}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
\chapter{Topics in Claims Reserving}
\section{section 1}
\subsection{section2}
\chapter{Conclusion}
\end{document}
```

If you want `report`, you have to do this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\chapter*{Declaration}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Declaration}
\chapter*{Preface}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface}
\chapter*{Abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Introduction}
\chapter{Topics in Claims Reserving}
\section{section 1}
\subsection{section2}
\chapter{Conclusion}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For all the odd things that may happen (and I don't understand properly)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{3em}
\cftsetindents{section}{3em}{1.5em}
\cftsetindents{subsection}{4.5em}{2.5em}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Declaration}
\chapter{Preface}
\chapter{Abstract}
\cleardoublepage
\setcounter{chapter}{1}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Introduction}
\chapter{Topics in Claims Reserving}
\section{section 1}
\subsection{section2}
\chapter{Conclusion}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Omitting the `*` is easy:-P. I still believe that the OP wants Roman Chapter numbers, not page numbers

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, without star they will be numbered. I guess that the OP doesn't want that.

Comment: @Sigur: Yes, perhaps... it's unclear

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, his MWE contains stared version and so doesn't appear in TOC.

Comment: @Sigur: I know that all, but the question is unclear. I think the OP is unaware about the `*` feature ;-)

Comment: @Harish Kumar how to do the same when working with a included file wich is a section or chapter !