# change the page numbering to uppercase roman numerals in report

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, report, roman

how i can transform the number pages for report to number roman like this form

[image]

i use this command

```
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{roman}
```

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244005/roman-numbering-in-table-of-contents-using-report

Comment: Replace `\pagenumbering{roman}` with `\pagenumbering{Roman}`?

Comment: great it's work thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code defines an `scroman` numbering:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\oldstyleroman}[1]{\expandafter\@oldstyleroman#1\@nil}
\def\@oldstyleroman#1#2\@nil{%
  \ifcat$\detokenize{#2}$%
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {\if#1ij\else#1\fi}% si #2 est vide
  {#1\@oldstyleroman#2\@nil}% si #2 n'est pas vide
}
\def\scroman#1{\expandafter\@scroman\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\def\@scroman#1{{\scshape\romannumeral #1}}
\makeatother
```

I also have a variant (`oldstyleroman` numbering) which reproduces a style in use until the middle  19th century: when the final letter of a number is an `i`, this final letter is replaced with `j`. It is also possible to define an  `oldstylescroman` numbering, which combines both features.

Comment: great it's work thank you