# Roman chapter numbers in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents

I have been trying to include the Acknowledgements in Latex with the following code

```
\include{Chapter/Title}
\include{Chapter/Acknowledgement}
\include{Chapter/Abstract}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\clearpage \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgement}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\tableofcontents
```

However the Acknowledgement is not added as a roman number to toc (It is numbered as 2). How can I fix this?

Comment: It depends on the class you are using, which is why a minimal, working example (MWE) is usually desirable. That said, a quick search turns this up: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244005/roman-numbering-in-table-of-contents-using-report

Comment: the \addcontentsline commands should be *inside* the \include.